# Choose Vertex Boost Graph Traversal

Tags: boost, graph, traversal, visitor-pattern, vertex

I am using boost::graph and the traversal algorithms (BFS / DFS). However, I need to modify the behavior as follows: when at a particular vertex, choose the next adjacent vertex based on some properties of the vertex. I know there are visitor concepts in boost:graph. I could not find a way to use them to determine the next vertex to choose. Any help??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you are wish to use a heuristic of some kind. Have a look at A-star search:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm